# google-chrome-app: JS not able to connect socket

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

The following code is part of a chrome app. I try to create a TCP socket (which actually works like expected) and now I want to connect the socket. I don't know why this does not work, I get no error (JS Console) but the execution seems to be blocked somehow, because the following lines are not executed.

```
var ip = 'localhost';
var port = 2000;

chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, function(info){

    console.log('try to connect socket: ' + ip + ':' + port);

    chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(info.socketId, ip, port, function(data){
        // this callback is not executed

        console.log('result of connection attempt: ' + data );

        chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(data){
            // ...
        });

        successCallback(info.socketId);
    });

    console.log('this line will never be printed... why?!');

});
```

Manifest.json

```
...
"sockets": {
    "udp": {},
    "tcp": {
        "connect": "127.0.0.1:*"
    },
    "tcpServer": {
        "listen": "127.0.0.1:*"
    }
}
...
```

To check the functionality I created a local TCP echo service:

```
ncat -l 2000 -k -c 'xargs -n1 echo'
```

Comment: Is your machine set up to recognize localhost as an alias of 127.0.0.1? Also the code you've supplied will fail because successCallback() is not defined.

Comment: also you have your event handler defined inside a callback (2 callbacks, no less). see the documentation about event pages for why this won't work - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/event_pages - basically you're adding that event listener, the process gets killed, started again when an event arrives, but there will be nowhere to deliver that event.